# Do hieroglyphs in Egypt depict aircraft?

Tags: history, aviation, egypt

In the article, [Impossible? 3,000 Year-Old Hieroglyphics Depict Modern Day Technology! Markings of the Fallen Angels?](http://beforeitsnews.com/prophecy/2014/02/impossible-3000-year-old-heiroglyphics-depict-modern-day-technology-markings-of-the-fallen-angels-shocking-video-and-pictures-2458842.html), they claim that there are aircraft depicted in 3000-year-old Egypt hieroglyphs:

> Decorating an Egyptian temple wall at Abydos are strange hieroglyphs which depict what appears to be modern day aircraft.

[image]

Is there a natural explanation for this not involving the supernatural claims of the article (i.e. angels)?

Comment: Sounds like [pareidolia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia) to me.

Comment: Am I the only one finding it difficult to see much resemblance between the pictured hieroglyphs and aircrafts?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo - without too much effort, I can spot 2..possibly a third

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*A* natural explanation is that these hieroglyphs in fact *don't* look like aircraft to many people and that those that *do* think they look like aircraft are experiencing [pareidolia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia).

I understand that this is speculative, but it is a speculative question. Other people have also proposed this same explanation. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicopter_hieroglyphs), [here](https://twitter.com/julio_scarlotti/status/340158146960039937), and [here](http://www.sciforums.com/Abydos-Helicopter-t-65746.html).

One factor that contributes to the current appearance of the hieroglyphs (regardless of what that appearance is interpreted as) is the [palimpsest effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palimpsest).

> Most Egyptologists strongly disagree that these carvings are anything but hieroglyphs. They guess that a recarving took place. Hieroglyphs were carved into the temple's sandstone wall. After some time, for whatever reason, new hieroglyphs were carved, but the hieroglyphs were only partially erased from the sandstone wall. Some of the old characters remained behind the new characters. People viewing the images today think the pictures look like modern modes of transportation. However, any resemblance to today's machines is simply a coincidence.

(From Ancient Astronauts, by Sue L Hamilton. p. 10)

Comment: We should show these to people who have never seen or heard of an aircraft.

Answer (score 33):

Further to Articuno's answer.

This is part of an inscription where one king's name was later overwritten with another's.

[image]
<sup>*from [The Abydos-Hieroglyph does NOT depict a Helicopter](http://members.tripod.com/~a_u_r_a/abydos.html)*</sup>

[image]
<sup>*From [helicopter hieroglyphs explained](http://raincool.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/helicopter-hieroglyphs-explained.html)*</sup>

Comment: Great visualization.